# GridView. View располагаются на разном уровне

Tags: android, gridview

Я пытаюсь сделать гридвью с двумя столбцами, чтобы все пространство item-а занимала картинка, а внизу на ней был текст.
Так должно быть

[image: как должно быть]

У меня же получаются большие отступы, текст вообще непонятно где.

[image: так получается]

Использую costraintLayout

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnWidth="150dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:scrollingCache="false"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

gv_item.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

adapter

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gv_item, null);

    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);

    Verses current = versesList.get(position);
    String imgName = "file:///android_asset/" + current.getImage();
    Picasso.get().load(imgName).into(image);
    tvTitle.setText(current.getTitle());
    return convertView;
}
```

Подскажите, где делаю ошибку

Comment: У вас разного размера картинки и текст, плюс всё завернуто в не предназначенный для таких целей `FrameLayout`. Можно попробовать использовать LinearLayout (чтобы не прыгал текст), но он так же не даст гарантию одноразмерности картинок. Тут либо хардкодить размер, либо делать `scaleType=fitXY` + `adjustViewBounds=true` а вообще - лучше перейти на `RecyclerView` с `GridLayoutManager` - это более прогрессивный и удобный виджет.

Comment: если вы хотите сделать подписи как на вашем примере, можно использовать `RelativeLayout` и для текста выставить атрибут `alignBottom = "@id/image_view"`

Comment: спасибо! я переделала на RecyclerView с GridLayoutManager. все работает